# How do i remove characters in a string between two specific characters?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to strip all characters in my string between "_" and " "

i've tried the split command but it takes everything after my parameter. I can't make it stop at " "

```
string = "adamannaogfrida_dfexosnfzg PeterMadsen_deinow_pk HjaltedDrejer_Weonfiweg"
```

Expected output: `adamannaogfrida PeterMadsen HjaltedDrejer`

Comment: what strip command, can you show in in your code

Comment: The first space, or last one?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh sorry i meant split command: string1 = string.split("_")[0]
This only outputs: adamannaogfrida

Comment: `split` gives you a list - `[0]` is the first thing. There might be other stuff after this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression sounds like a competitive candidate:

```
import re
s = re.sub("_[^ ]*( |$)", " ", string)
print(s)
```

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Given the expected output I'd use `split` instead of `strip`:

```
s = "adamannaogfrida_dfexosnfzg PeterMadsen_deinow_pk HjaltedDrejer_Weonfiweg"

out = [x.split("_")[0] for x in s.split()]
out
# ['adamannaogfrida', 'PeterMadsen', 'HjaltedDrejer']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regular expression approach:

```
re.sub(r'_.+?\b', '', 'adamannaogfrida_dfexosnfzg PeterMadsen_deinow_pk HjaltedDrejer_Weonfiweg')
#'adamannaogfrida PeterMadsen HjaltedDrejer'
```